# AngularJS output text box value after clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple form in angularjs, that inputs value a and value b. when I click the button, I want the values to be alerted out. How do I do that?

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <p><label>value a : </label><input type="text" ng-model="valuea" name="valuea" id="valuea" /></p>
    <p><label>value b  : </label><input name="valueb" id="valueb" ng-model="valueb"/></p>

    <button type="button" ng-click = "add()"  >Sign In</button> 
</div>

<script>
   angular.module('myApp', [])
   .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   function myController($scope) {
       $scope.add = function(){
           alert("valuea:"+$scope.valuea);
           alert("valueb:"+$scope.valueb);
       } 
   };
}]);
```

Comment: when i click sign in, the value of of valuea and vllue2 doesn't got alert. you can see the code here https://jsfiddle.net/t8h35m0o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
      <p>
        <label>value a : </label><input type="text" ng-model="valuea" name="valuea" id="valuea" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>value b : </label><input name="valueb" id="valueb" ng-model="valueb" />
      </p>

      <button type="button" ng-click="add()">Sign In</button>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.add = function() {
    alert("valuea:" + $scope.valuea);
    alert("valueb:" + $scope.valueb);
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are certain issues with your code. In your `html` there is no module `myApp`. Also within your controller callback, there is no need to add the separate function with the controller name `function myController() {}`.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
   .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.add = function(){
           alert("valuea: "+$scope.valuea);
           alert("valueb: "+$scope.valueb);
       } 
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
      <p><label>value a : </label><input type="text" ng-model="valuea" name="valuea" id="valuea" /></p>
      <p><label>value b  : </label><input name="valueb" id="valueb" ng-model="valueb"/></p>
      <button type="button" ng-click = "add()"  >Sign In</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

See working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/otqzk6ua/